# How to reduce the number of variables in MATLAB function?

Tags: matlab

How can I change the variables in MATLAB numeric function?
for example, the original function is:

```
function y = myfile1(a,b,c)
y = a*b*c
end
```

and I want to convert it into this form:

```
function y = myfile2(x)
y = x(1)*x(2)*x(3)
end
```

is there any possible way to do it? (of course, not manually edit it)
Thanks

Comment: You can call it like that- `myfile1(x(1),x(2),x(3))`. You can't pass this function a single input without change it.

Comment: Is that possible to write a another function to change it automatically?

Comment: If you want another function, I didn't understand it... You don't need, I'll write the new function in the answers.

Comment: So you want to change the function without changing the function? I don't get it

Comment: change the function variable without change the form. It's solved. Thanks for concerning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the vector `x` to another function, `myfile2`, then call `myfile1` with the vector numbers, like that:

```
function y = myfile2(x)
y = myfile1(x(1),x(2),x(3))
end
```

So that `a,b,c` in the function `myfile1` will be actually `x(1), x(2), x(3)`.

Comment: OMG! it is that simple! OMG.Thank you very much!

Comment: You welcome. Actually I don't understand  why not using directly the mutiplication, like in YOUR `myfile2`. It's exactly the same.

Comment: because the real function is very complicate, here is just an simple example.